# Output results of a search for usage of a pardot-form

Tags: php, html

I'm always down to learn better ways of doing thing and I wanted to see if I can get an input from the community to see if there is a way that I can improve this function:

```php
function pardot_dashboard_query()
{
    $args = [
        's'         => '<!-- wp:acf/pardot-form ',
        'sentence'  => 1,
        'post_type' => [
            'post',
            'page'
        ],
    ];
    $pardot_posts = get_posts($args);
    if (!$pardot_posts) {
        echo 'There are no active Pardot Forms.';
        return;
    }
    echo '<p>The Pardot Form is active on the following pages/posts:</p>'; ?>
    <ul>
        <?php foreach ($pardot_posts as $post): ?>
            <li><a href="<?= $post->guid ?>"><?= $post->post_title ?: 'No title available' ?><?= ' (' . ucfirst($post->post_type) . ')' ?></a></li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
    <?php
}
```

If there are other means of outputs and or ways to shrink it down - All help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I generally don't advocate for printing any content from within a function, but I'll not dwell on this because it is a somewhat common practice for WordPressers.

- Name your function to clearly express what it does. Please greater importance on clarity than brevity.
- declare the return value as `void` to help you and your IDE to better understand the function's behavior.
- avoid single-use variable declarations unless they are valuably self-documenting.
- I don't see you using excessive spacing like many WP devs, so kudos for that.
- I prefer curly brace syntax for language construct looping.  I don't personally find the verbose loop end to be valuable.
- use `printf()` and `sprintf()` to elegantly marry variables and expressions into a template string.  This is easier to read than a bunch of concatenation and interpolation.
- I prefer not to jump in and out of php tags, so I'll demonstrate staying inside of PHP the whole time.
- I'm not sold on that `href` value being legit. Is that value actually a valid url?

Code:

```
function printPardotDashboardItems(): void
{
    $pardot_posts = get_posts([
        's'         => '<!-- wp:acf/pardot-form ',
        'sentence'  => 1,
        'post_type' => [
            'post',
            'page'
        ],
    ]);
    if (!$pardot_posts) {
        echo '<p>There are no active Pardot Forms.</p>';
    } else {
        $items = [];
        foreach ($pardot_posts as $post) {
            $items[] = sprintf(
                '<li><a href="%s">%s (%s)</a></li>',
                $post->guid,
                $post->post_title ?: 'No title available',
                ucfirst($post->post_type)
            );
        }
        printf(
            '<p>The Pardot Form is active on the following pages/posts:</p><ul>%s</ul>',
            implode("\n", $items)
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: This works flawlessly! Thanks @mickmackusa, I learned something new with this technique - Surprisingly, the href actually does come back as an accurate return.